# laravel Homestead starting with error and no input file

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I was trying to update my MacBook to the newest version.
Also downloaded and installed the newest version of homestead, virtualbox and vagrant.
I also destroyed my old virtual machines and wanted to start fresh.

I had a couple of problems to get all of them to run again. But now, i got the machine running (vagrant up). At the end i get this error, but dont know what exactly i have to do:

```
homestead-7: Updating to version 1.8.3 (stable channel).
homestead-7:    
homestead-7:                                                                                                        
homestead-7:   [ErrorException]                                                                                     
homestead-7:   rename(/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied  
homestead-7:                                                                                                        
homestead-7: 
homestead-7: self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--set-channel-only] [--] [<version>]
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Also, i configured my paths in homestead.yaml like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox


authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
       to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: testen.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/testen/public
```

also configured it in the hosts. But when i open the link in my browser, it just says "No input file specified."
I log via vagrant ssh to the machine and check the path. It is there.
maybe getting no input file because of the previous error? I really don't know what i have to repair...

Comment: Use Valet instead.

Comment: What command you used, vagrant up/ vagrant up --provision?

Comment: i just installed valet and got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the composer.phar file is present? Check your access rights?

Comment: i would like to check it... but i dont even know where it is or should be. And how to check the rights...